valid euclidean distance meaurement method to compare different financial price time series datsets
I am trying to determine if I can use euclidean distance to measure and compare any two financial time series data sets by total Length of the lines they plot on a chart, using the formula for euclidean distance D = square root of ((x2 − x1)2 + (y2 − y1)2). My process would be to then use this data for x: the count of how many time periods have passed starting from 0,  and for y: the running sum of the percent change between price periods/samples. I have attached a hypothetical data set. I would keep the time sampling interval the same for any datsets I compare. Is this method a valid way to compare data sets in regards to LENGTH of lines that they plot?


